# View a buffer in read-only mode in a window while editing it in another window

Tags: read-only-mode

A buffer can be made write-protected by toggling the read-only mode via `M-x toggle-read-only`. 
Is there a way to make a buffer read-only in a window, while editing it in another window?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your original buffer, where you want to keep editing it :

```
M-x clone-indirect-buffer
```

This would create another buffer, and by default open it in another window too. Initially both of these are editable. But a buffer specific mode change can be made in the second one - which will now become read only after you do the following :

```
M-x read-only-mode
```

Now this second buffer is your buffer in read-only mode - same content as the earlier read-write buffer.

Comment: could you please add some explanation?

Comment: Ah, ok, one min. Since you were using M-x and toggling modes already, I thought you would understand very easily.

Comment: Thanks. IMO, it is better to add some explanation along with the commands for the general audience.